# Session handling in OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, scribe

I am writing an application which will connect to multiple email servers using OAuth. As part of initial connection establishment, user will be prompted to give access to application. After granting access, it will redirect to the url provided while registering the application in OAuth API.

Now i want to identify for which user the access token and refresh token belongs after redirect url comes to my application. I want to treat all requests happening in one user session as unique. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I followed your question, but my understanding is that you want to determine some of the information about the user that's just logged into your API client.  You can get email addresses by requesting the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope and running a oauth2/userinfo GET request:

```
gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp,raw)...
```

Depending on which scopes you have access too, you will also get a display name and some other info.  Best bet is just to `console.log(resp)` and pick out what you want to use.

Comment: after reading some more documentation, i arrived at same solution. Once the request comes back, i am retrieving email id and some unique id which is assigned to user by application(this is taken from session) and using both of them for further processing and storing in DB